# Editting an existing input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to edit an input value but all what happens is the todo.name and editingText are getting concatenated together with every character im adding.

What i'm trying to do basically is clicking on the edit button, and then have the input field open with the existing data (as in, if i click on "Feed the dog" i'll have the input "Feed the dog" and then be able to edit that text).

````
import Todo from "./Todo";
import AddTodo from "./AddTodo";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const TodoList = () => {
  //Handlers Add/Remove/RemoveAll/Edit
  const addTodoHandler = (input) => {
    setTodos([
      ...todos,
      {
        name: input,
        id: uuidv4(),
      },
    ]);
  };

  const removeTodosHandler = () => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete everything?")) {
      setTodos([]);
    }
  };

  const removeTodoHandler = (id) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
  };

  //edit functions
  const editTodo = (id) => {
    const updatedTodos = [...todos].map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.name = editingText;
      }
      return todo;
    });
    setTodos(updatedTodos);
    setTodoEditing(null);
    setEditingText("");
  };

  //Todo list state
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  //Edit states
  const [todoEditing, setTodoEditing] = useState(null);
  const [editingText, setEditingText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {todos.map((todo) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Todo name={todo.name} key={todo.id} />
              <button onClick={() => removeTodoHandler(todo.id)}>X</button>
              <button onClick={() => setTodoEditing(todo.id)}>Edit</button>

              {todoEditing === todo.id ? (
                <form>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => setEditingText(e.target.value)}
                    value={todo.name + editingText}
                  />
                  <button onClick={() => editTodo(todo.id)}>v</button>
                </form>
              ) : (
                <div></div>
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <AddTodo
        handleAddTodo={addTodoHandler}
        removeTodosHandler={removeTodosHandler}
        revemoveTodoHandler={removeTodoHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoList;```

Every help apprecaited!
````

Comment: `const [editingText, setEditingText] = useState(todo.name);` and for input field `value={editingText}` try this

Comment: I have tried it ,i'm getting 'todo' is not defined.